# Sony Vaio Network controller driver not found

Tags: wireless-networking, sony-vaio

My notebook (Sony Vaio with product name `VPCF236FM`) does not find any driver for network adapter. I tried to search with it's hardware id (`pci ven_8086&dev_0885&cc_0280`) but still nothing helpful. I can connect to the internet using LAN Cable but I can't use WiFi for searching any available wireless connections, 
my OS is win7 x64

Comment: Have you checked the Sony site?  What OS are you using?

Comment: When it comes to laptops, your best bet is always the manufacturer's website. In your case, here is the relevant page: http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=VPCF236FM&LOC=3#/downloadTab

Comment: I checked , Download drivers that they said , but didn't helped , also I'm using win7 64bit :)

Comment: @Windos from your link U have downloaded this in Network "Realtek® PCIe GBE Family Controller" , install it , and nothing helped , also I download some other drivers , can they make some problems?

Comment: Did you download the one under Wireless LAN? (Intel® Centrino® Wireless-N 6150 Driver)

If you're downloading the one under Network, which it sounds like you are, you'll only get wired LAN.

Comment: As I remember I download it also , but I'll try it again , Please leave your comments as answers , so I can up vote them :) , thanks all for helping :)

Comment: Dear @Windos downloading this driver from sonevaio's page helped , and now it works , so if you post your comment like answer , I can be thankful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sony eSupport - VPCF236FM - Support](http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=VPCF236FM&template_id=1&region_id=1&tab=download#/downloadTab)

> - CRITICAL VAIO® Easy Connect Software Update Release Date 1/20/2012 Version 1.1.2.01120
>
>   This utility updates the VAIO Easy Connect software to resolve a
>     buffer overflow security issue.
> - Intel® Centrino® Wireless-N 6150 Driver Release Date 8/29/2011 Version 14.1.1.3
>
>   This utility installs the originally shipped version of the Intel
>     Centrino Wireless-N 6150 driver.

Comment: The OP said they already tried downloading the drivers.

Comment: Specifies not only the driver but also the utility manages the connection WiFi with critical update.
And PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0885&CC_0280 it Intel® Centrino® Wireless-N 6150.

Comment: thanks for help , I have download the drivers , I'll try now with easy connect software update , I'll make you know if something :)

Comment: If need search unknown device in command string, write in cmd `DEVCON FindAll =Unknown | FIND "\"` and good luck!

Comment: Tell the truth downloading Wireless-N 6150 Driver Release , helped , and now it works , I remember that I have downloaded it , but from another web page, So thank you very much :)

Comment: Strangely enough it is the propagation of the problem. Errors in the propagation of the inf files thing. Often on the site of one manufacturer are both ways, driver. You can unpack the driver and manually search ID. But this kind of perversion. Good luck!